# Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS - SSH / x2go session work fine, but monitor remains black when sitting in front of the computer

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, screen

Cheers everyone,

As the headline states:
All remote sessions via SSH / x2go work completely normal, but when one sits in front of the computer, monitors remain black. I have restarted **gdm** using `sudo systemctl restart gdm`, with no success.
After a restart all is back to normal, but I would really like to not restart every time this happens.

I do not know if it is relevant, but we have a NVIDIA RTX A6000 installed running driver version: 470.182.03.

I would really appreciate if you had ideas on how to solve this.
Thanks in advance!